# Image fit flexbox of certain dimensions

Tags: html, css, image

So, I made a similar question a while ago of how an img can fit a div and the answer was to set `height: 100%` and `width: 100%` of the image and it worked good. But now I also use a `flexbox` inside that div and the img still overflows at bottom...

```css
.d1 {
  background: green;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.d2 {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
}

.img1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <div class="d2">
    <img class="img1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3c/Cityoflondon2019june.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so distorting the image isn't a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Give `height:100%` to the parent div of your image. Also adjust your padding or use `calc` for setting height `height:calc(100% - 10px)` See below.

```css
.d1 {
  background: green;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.d2 {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
}

.img1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <div class="d2">
    <img class="img1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3c/Cityoflondon2019june.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you will need to add height to img container and object-fit:cover property to img also remove the height from img. PS: object fit will keep the aspect ratio of the image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.d1 {
    background: green;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.d2 {
    background: red;
    display: flex;
    padding: 5px;
    height: calc(100% - 10px); // minus padding
}
.img1 {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover; //not supported in IE
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="d1">
    <div class="d2">
        <img class="img1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3c/Cityoflondon2019june.jpg">
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

codepen link https://codepen.io/madeelahsan/pen/xxxVpbm

Comment: you can inherit the height instead of using `calc` with  `height: inherit` and then use  `box-sizing: border-box` to absorb padding / border into the height / width. [Example](https://codepen.io/misterManSam/pen/LYYNQEZ)

Answer (score 0):

Move height and width from `.d1` to `.d2`.

```
.d2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}
```